# Display none not working with dynamically Id using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with jquery and i am trying to enable/disable using ajax jquery,Function working but showing result after
page refresh,ajax response condition is not working(dynamically),

Here is my html

```
<td>
    <?php if(($ban->status)==1) {?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="disable <?php echo($ban->id); ?>" onclick="enable(<?php echo($ban->id); ?>)">Disable</button>
 <?php }else{ ?>
                                            
<button type="button" id="enable <?php echo($ban->id); ?>" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enable(<?php echo($ban->id); ?>)">Enable</button>
<?php }?>
</td>
```

Here is my ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enable(id) {
       var id = id;
         alert(id);
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "<?php echo base_url('upload_controller/enable');?>",
               data: {'id': id},
               cache: false,
               dataType: "html",
               async: false,
               success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                $('#response').html(data);
if (jQuery.trim(data) == "disabled") 
              {
                    document.getElementById(`enable ${id}`).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById(`disable ${id}`).style.display = "block";
                 }
              else  // if status enabled ( query working fine)
                  {
                    document.getElementById(`disable ${id}`).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById(`enable ${id}`).style.display = "block";
                   }    
}
           });
         
    }
</script>
```

Here is my controller

public function enable(){

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
        $sql = "SELECT status from banner WHERE id=$id";
        $querys=$this->db->query($sql);
        $rtnArr = $querys->row_array();
        //echo "<pre>";print_R($rtnArr);
        $status=$rtnArr['status'];
        //die();
        if($status=="1")
            {
                    $sql = "UPDATE banner SET status=0 WHERE id=$id";
                    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
                    echo "disabled";
                    die();
            }
        else
            {
                    $sql = "UPDATE banner SET status=1 WHERE id=$id";
                    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
                    echo "enabled";
            }   

    }
```

Comment: ids cannot contain whitespaces. Try ``enable-${id}``

Comment: @CodeSpirit: not working, Problem in "hide/show" lines

Comment: Please add all relevant HTML code. What does `upload_controller/enable` return?

Comment: @Code Spirit: update my question now you can see my "upload_controller" function

Comment: Please learn more about PHP and JS especially client/server relation. In your PHP script you have to return a result which you handle in your JS callback and then you have to update the `DOM` (html) by yourself. There is no interoperation between PHP and HTML. Once your HTML is delivered to your browser its "disconnected" from your PHP. HTML is only PHP output. 1. Make AJAX request, 2. On success update html/dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to show how you can use a single button and toggle it's style and text. I did it this way thinking you may have multiple buttons to toggle, though it works fine with one. TO keep it flexible, we put the status and the id into data-attributes. You can test it here, and it will show the toggle, but to test it with your code, remove the part that is commented for you to remove.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-enable').each(function() {
    setButton($(this), +$(this).attr('data-status'))
  })

  $('.btn-enable').click(function() {
    // remove the next 2 lines for your actual code. This is for the snippet test
    setButton($(this), +$(this).attr('data-status') === 1 ? 0 : 1)
    return

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "<?php echo base_url('upload_controller/enable');?>",
      data: {
        'id': $(this).data('id')
      },
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $('#response').html(data);
        if (jQuery.trim(data) == "disabled") setButton($(this), 0)
        else setButton($(this), 1)
      }

    })
  })
})

function setButton(button, status) {
  console.log(status)
  let cl = status ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-success';
  let text = status ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
  $(button).removeClass(['btn-warning', 'btn-success']);
  $(button).addClass(cl);
  $(button).attr('data-status', status);

  $(button).text(text)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-enable" data-id='<?php echo($ban->id); ?>' data-status="<?php echo($ban->status); ?>"></button>
```